# Nginx match path on any domain name

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I want to configure nginx so that a specific path on every domain name routes to a certain location. The use case is I want to be able to point lets encrypt at this location to drop the verification files and have it work for every domain.

I am aware nginx has `location` blocks that can be used in server blocks but I'm not aware of a way to have a server block that accepts all domain names when the path is correct even when other server blocks specify a domain to listen on.

Comment: You can't. The best solution is to place the common `location` statement into a separate file and use `include` to pull it into every `server` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx selects a `server` block to process a request based on the values of the `listen` and `server_name` directives. The best way to insert common code into a number of `server` blocks (or anywhere else in an Nginx configuration) is to place them into a separate file and use the `include` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

For example:

In a file called `wellknown.conf`:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/ {
    root /path/to/root;
}
```

In each `server` block:

```
server {
    ...
    include wellknown.conf;
    ...
}
```

Without any directory path, the file will be located within the same directory as the `nginx.conf` file. Obviously, these files can be placed elsewhere within the file system, but avoid directories like `sites-enabled`, `sites-available` and `conf.d` as these already have a specific purpose.

The `^~` modifier on the `location` directive makes it unambiguous and avoids any regular expression `location` taking precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.